# Не работает @Autowired в jUnit тестах

Tags: java, spring, junit

какой уже день не могу решить проблему, пытался разными способами. Суть проблемы: надо написать jUnit тесты на DAOimpl слой. Однако, когда пытаюсь заавтовайрить код, либо он не автовайрится, либо выдает ошибку (когда пытался сделать через spring boot аннотации или xml файл)

[image: структура проекта]

фрагмент кода CommentDAOimpl

```
// фрагмент кода CommentDAOimpl
package ru.vegd.dao.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.vegd.dao.CommentDAO;
import ru.vegd.entity.Comment;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CommentDAOimpl implements CommentDAO {

    private final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(CommentDAOimpl.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    private static final String SQL_GETALL = "SELECT * FROM \"Comments\"";
    private static final String SQL_ADD = "INSERT INTO \"Comments\" (news_id, author_id, comment_text, creation_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private static final String SQL_READ = "SELECT * FROM \"Comments\" WHERE comments_id = ?";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE = "DELETE FROM \"Comments\" WHERE \"Comments\".\"comment_id\" = ?";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE \"Comments\" SET news_id = ?, author_id = ?, comment_text = ? WHERE comments_id = ?";

    @Override
    public List getAll() throws SQLException {

        List<Comment> commentList = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try  {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_GETALL);


            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Comment comment = new Comment();

                comment.setComment_id(resultSet.getLong("comments_id"));
                comment.setNews_id(resultSet.getLong("news_id"));
                comment.setAuthor_id(resultSet.getLong("author_id"));
                comment.setComment_text(resultSet.getString("comment_text"));
                comment.setSending_date(resultSet.getTimestamp("creation_date"));

                commentList.add(comment);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.warn("Request eror");
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

        return commentList;
    }
```

CommentDAOimplTest

```
//CommentDAOimplTest
package ru.vegd.dao.impl;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import ru.vegd.dao.CommentDAO;
import ru.vegd.entity.Comment;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/springTest.xml")
public class CommentDAOimplTest {

        @Autowired
        CommentDAO commentDAO; // не автовайрится сюда

        Comment comment = new Comment();

    @Test
    public void getAll() throws SQLException {

        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
        comment.setComment_id(8L);
        comment.setNews_id(1L);
        comment.setAuthor_id(4L);
        comment.setComment_text("nice");
        comment.setSending_date(Timestamp.valueOf("2019-11-11 00:00:09.959"));
        comments.add(comment);
        System.out.println(commentDAO);
        /*Assert.assertEquals(comments.get(0), commentDAO.getAll().get(0));*/

    }
}
```

springTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="ru.vegd/" />
</beans>
```

Сама ошибка

```
00:23:26.916 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class ru.vegd.dao.impl.CommentDAOimplTest]
00:23:26.930 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
00:23:26.947 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
00:23:26.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [ru.vegd.dao.impl.CommentDAOimplTest] from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
00:23:27.012 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader - Delegating to GenericXmlContextLoader to process context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@6e1567f1 declaringClass = 'ru.vegd.dao.impl.CommentDAOimplTest', classes = '{}', locations = '{/springTest.xml}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader'].
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy

    at org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
```

Process finished with exit code -1

В итоге при запуске теста вылетает ошибка.
Может, кто сталкивался уже с подобным или знает решение, буду рад любой помощи!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>news-portal</name>
  <groupId>ru.vegadev</groupId>
  <artifactId>news-portal</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

      <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя вероятно проблема с версиями spring-библиотек, которые ты подключаешь в своём проекте. Ошибка

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
```

говорит о том, что у тебя отсутствует класс [org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations.SearchStrategy.html), который появился в версии **5.2.0** и является частью `spring-core`. Судя по стэку исключение падает при работе метода [TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/support/TestPropertySourceUtils.java#L74).

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что у тебя используется артефакт `spring-test` версии **5.2.0** или выше, а версия `spring-core` ниже указанной. Тебе надо выровнять версию `spring-test` к версии `spring-core`.

P.S. Тут неплохо бы было приложить сборочный файл (`pom.xml` или `build.gradle`), если таковой имеется.

**Update**

Поменяй

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

на

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

Comment: Добавил в конец вопроса pom.xml, спасибо за отзывчивость

Comment: @VincentVega дополнил ответ